# how to include using gradle the java api of z3 (jar and so files)

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, z3

I am using Idea, Z3, and Gradle but I am having a hard time getting Gradle to properly include the java-api of Z3 (https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3 ; https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/tree/master/examples/java).

Basically, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. java -cp com.microsoft.z3.jar:. JavaExample` should be sufficient from the shell (LD_LIBRARY_PATH for the `.so` files).
But how may I include this information in the gradle build file?
I checked the documentation and search myself but I found no explanation that was clear enough for me...